# select and set border on all td but the first one

Tags: css

i'm having hard time for a pretty silly simple task
i need to add a border 1px on evey row, bu the first one...adding border to TR doesnt seem to work...

```
    <div id="container1"> 
        <table>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>2</td></tr>
            <tr><td>3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>4</td></tr>
            <tr><td>5</td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>         
    <div id="container2"> 
        <table>
            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>2</td></tr>
            <tr><td>3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>4</td></tr>
            <tr><td>5</td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
td { border:1px solid black}
tr:first-child > td { border:none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: in the title you say that you want to set a border to the td-s and in the question you say that you want to set a border to every row (a.k.a. tr). My examples set a border on the tr-s.

I hope one of these meets your needs:

```
tr:not(:first-child) {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

---

```
tr {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#container1 tr:first-child {
    border: inherit;
}
```